# Nginx + Node + DigitalOcean: connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream

Tags: nginx, dns, digital-ocean

I'm trying to use Nginx to forward all requests to my domain (sofy.site) to a Node app running on my droplet. I also want to use SSL because the app can only work over https due to some limiting factors.

I've been on this task for the past 3-4 hours and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. If I follow some question somewhere it fixes that issue but brings up another issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my server configuration: 
**NOTE:** I am not using the Nginx config file but instead have a file named 'node' in /etc/nginx/sites-available/ which I have linked with a file with the same name under /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/.

```
upstream sofy {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {
     listen 80;
     listen 433 ssl;

     server_name sofy.site;
     return 302 $scheme://www.sofy.site/$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot

    server_name www.sofy.site;  

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sofy.site/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sofy.site/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    # pass the request to the node.js server with the correct headers
    # and much more can be added, see nginx config options

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://sofy;
      proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    }
}
```

When I try to open the page https://sofy.site it shows the error '502 Bad gateway' with another text saying 'nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)'

This is what /var/log/nginx/error.log looks like:

```
2019/08/04 15:54:35 [error] 27684#27684: *28 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 183.87.41.80, server: sofy.site, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://127.0.0.1:3000/favicon.ico", host: "www.sofy.site", referrer: "https://www.sofy.site/"
2019/08/04 15:55:04 [error] 27684#27684: *28 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 183.87.41.80, server: sofy.site, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://127.0.0.1:3000/", host: "www.sofy.site"
2019/08/04 15:55:05 [error] 27684#27684: *28 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 183.87.41.80, server: sofy.site, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://127.0.0.1:3000/favicon.ico", host: "www.sofy.site", referrer: "https://www.sofy.site/"
2019/08/04 15:56:22 [error] 27684#27684: *35 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 183.87.41.80, server: sofy.site, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://127.0.0.1:3000/", host: "www.sofy.site"
2019/08/04 15:56:22 [error] 27684#27684: *35 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 183.87.41.80, server: sofy.site, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://127.0.0.1:3000/favicon.ico", host: "www.sofy.site", referrer: "https://www.sofy.site/"
2019/08/04 15:56:22 [error] 27684#27684: *35 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 183.87.41.80, server: sofy.site, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://127.0.0.1:3000/", host: "www.sofy.site"
2019/08/04 15:56:23 [error] 27684#27684: *35 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 183.87.41.80, server: sofy.site, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://127.0.0.1:3000/favicon.ico", host: "www.sofy.site", referrer: "https://www.sofy.site/"
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by using this as the config file 'node':

```
upstream sofy {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot

    server_name sofy.site www.sofy.site;  

    # pass the request to the node.js server with the correct headers
    # and much more can be added, see nginx config options

    location / {
     proxy_pass http://sofy;
     proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sofy.site/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sofy.site/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```